# Triggers inside User Control WPF Child Elements included

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<UserControl x:Class="my.Resources.NavButtons"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myProject.Resources"
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:Meziantou.WpfFontAwesome;assembly=Meziantou.WpfFontAwesome"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButtons}">
            <!-- Trying to set a hover like trigger here. -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <!-- Change background of main border-->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                    <!-- Change foreground color here -->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource hFontColor}"/>
                    <!-- Change border thickness color here -->
                    <Settter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LiteBlue}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource Primary}" BorderThickness="4,0,0,0" Height="30" Cursor="Hand">
                <Border Padding="0 5 0 5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <fa:FontAwesomeIcon Grid.Column="0" SolidIcon="{Binding Icon}" Foreground="{StaticResource pFontColor}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}"  Foreground="{StaticResource pFontColor}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Border>

</UserControl>
```

I'm just working with UserControls and trying to figure out how to get triggers to work on my entire "Button" seamlessly, and maybe with animation but I'll work with that later.

Can anyone explain to me more what I'm doing wrong here with the triggers? As currently when the mouse is over the object it does nothing that is set in the trigger. I'm thinking it's not targeting the correct property within the main button. Do I need to add more to the target type?

Comment: Your question needs some improvement. It must include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having. Also, you need to actually describe that problem. Explain _precisely_ what the code you have does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you are unable to figure out.

Comment: I've updated it a little more, not exactly sure why this doesn't seem clean-cut as I'm asking if the style-setters are correct or if I have the user control all wrong.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking, as Peter mentioned you need to provide a minimal and reproducible example. Your current code cannot be reproduced as you are using undefined types. When that is said, not all `Properties` can be updated directly from `Styles` as some properties can be hard coded in the `Template`. `Button` is a very good example. `Triggers` in the `Style` cannot update `Background`, for that you need to modify the `Template`. See my answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36641501/2289942

Comment: I've added my answer with precedent

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was class precedence and changing triggers to Data binding triggers. Once I took out the inline styles and added them to the Style everything went well. Also, I needed to target each element as an individual, thus changing this ---

to this ---

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButtons}">
            <!-- Trying to set a hover like trigger here. -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <!-- Change background of main border-->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                    <!-- Change foreground color here -->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource hFontColor}"/>
                    <!-- Change border thickness color here -->
                    <Settter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LiteBlue}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

```
        <!-- get the child element FA for font awesome icons -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type fa:FontAwesomeIcon}">
            <!-- have to set explicitly inside style because of presedence -->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource pFontColor}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Change the property on trigger of Mouse Over event on the Border element-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border,AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource hFontColor}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <!-- have to set explicitly inside style because of presedence -->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource pFontColor}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Change the property on trigger of Mouse Over event on the Border element-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border,AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource hFontColor}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <!-- have to set explicitly inside style because of presedence -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Change the property on trigger of Mouse Over event on the Border element-->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightBlue}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButtons}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <!-- Trying to set a default background color. -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua" />
        </Style.Setters>
        <!-- Trying to set a hover like trigger here. -->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <!-- Change background of main border-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                <!-- Change foreground color here -->
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource hFontColor}"/>
                <!-- Change border thickness color here -->
                <Settter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LiteBlue}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

trying to set a default color for background.